# Speed of an object in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a simple pygame program that only consists of moving a box around the screen. The box moves very fast and I want to know how to control the speed. In my code the updated position is moved by 1 and not smaller because if the number is not an integer it makes things more complicated.

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

WINDOWWIDTH = 400
WINDOWHEIGHT = 400
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Box")

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
size1 = 20
size2 = 2
#character = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 20, 30)
player = pygame.Surface((40,40))




pos1 = 100
pos2 = 100


MOVESPEED = 6

x = 1

while True:
    if pos1 == WINDOWWIDTH - 40 and pos1 > 0:
        pos1 -= 1
        x += 1
    elif pos1 < WINDOWWIDTH - 40 and x == 1:
        pos1 += 1
    elif x ==2:
        pos1 -= 1


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:

                pos1 -= 5
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                pos1 += 4


    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

    #screen.blit(character)



    windowSurface.blit(player, (pos1, pos2))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 8):

You should put the following bit of code in your "while True:" loop somewhere:

```
clock.tick([insert fps here])
```

and put this somewhere before the loop:

```
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
```

This will not allow the loop to run more than the number of times you enter per second, and hopefully slow the cube down.

Comment: This is the only real useful answer. Why move an object less than a pixel, that doesnt make sense? Adding an FPS limit will definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't alter the position in every iteration of your loop.

Instead of

```
while True:
  if ... :
    pos1 += 1
  ...
```

use somethinig like this:

```
tmp = 0

while True:
  if ... :
    tmp += 1
    if tmp == 10:
      pos1 += 1
      tmp = 0
  ...
```

or

```
tmp = 0

while True:
  if ... and not tmp % 10:
      pos1 += 1
  ...
```

where you adjust `10` to a value that will suit you.

Also, you may want to limit the framerate of your programm to get a (more or less) constant framerate using a [Clock](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock).

Comment: yes using a Clock is definately what you want to do, if you want similiar speed on different computers -- and if you don't want to wast a whole processor moving that box

Answer (score 2):

You could use floats to store the positions after all. Change the update values in the while loop to something smaller, e.g. `pos1 += 0.25`. Then just make sure to blit integers: `windowSurface.blit(player, (int(pos1), int(pos2)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I normally also use integers for most positions but when I say pygame to draw my object/sprite/... to the screen I always divide the position by 10 so that I have 10 steps of values since the objects moves one step on the screen.

Organisation of this is not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum velocity you can have is 1 but there is a way to slow it down more by controlling time.

For example, moving the box with velocity 1 every 100ms instead of every frame makes the movement appear significantly slower.

See implementation below:

```
# initialize clock object outside of main loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
time = 0

while 1:

    time = time + clock.get_time()
    if time >= 100:

        # Your movement implementation here

        time = 0 # Reset timer at the end
```