# how do i slow down, when it goes from 10 y to 510 y

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, clock, snakebite

how do i slow this down? right now it instantly goes down/left/up/right. I know it has to do with the time module but i have no idea how to implement it. Basically I want to SLOW down the process from 10 y to 490 y. Not add a delay but slow down the process like making it go in slow motion. I even tried the pygame clock with 120fps but it did not work

````
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 120

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
background = pygame.image.load('back.png')
surface.blit(background, (0, 0))
block = pygame.image.load('block.png').convert()
block_y = 0
block_x = 0
surface.blit(block, (block_x, block_y))

def draw():
    surface.blit(background, (0, 0))
    surface.blit(block, (block_x, block_y))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                block_y -= 10
                draw()
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                block_y += 10
                draw()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                block_x -= 10
                draw()
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                block_x += 10
                draw()
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            clock.tick(fps)
            if event.key == K_UP:
                block_y -= 10
                draw()
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                block_y += 490
                draw()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                block_x -= 100
                draw()
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                block_x += 510
                draw()
    ```
````

Comment: The position [change] is 10 pixels per frame, not 10 pixels per second. [Consider using clock.tick(fps) in here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942011/speed-of-an-object-in-pygame/12231013].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speed of an object in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942011/speed-of-an-object-in-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a great solution as it is not frame rate independent (see FaranAiki’s comment) but here you go (change `speed` to, uh, change speed. You may also want to decrease your frame rate):

```py
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 120
speed=1
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
background = pygame.image.load('back.png')
surface.blit(background, (0, 0))
block = pygame.image.load('block.png').convert()
block_y = 0
block_x = 0
surface.blit(block, (block_x, block_y))

def draw():
    surface.blit(background, (0, 0))
    surface.blit(block, (block_x, block_y))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                block_y -= speed
                draw()
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                block_y += speed
                draw()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                block_x -= speed
                draw()
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                block_x += speed
                draw()
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            clock.tick(fps)
            if event.key == K_UP:
                block_y -= 10
                draw()
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                block_y += 490
                draw()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                block_x -= 100
                draw()
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                block_x += 510
                draw()
```